# Append to default __str__ output implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

How can I add on to the default `__str__` so that the typical output of a class object as well as custom string is outputted when printing the object?

```
class foo():
    .
    .
    .    

someObject = foo()
print(someObject)
>> <__main__.o object at 0x00000270E2C1E400> "Some additonal stuff"
```

Comment: Is `someObject` a class that you have defined?

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes it is, I added more code to be more clear.

Comment: @Masoud It's different, the link you provided shows how to overwrite the current `__str__` implementation instead of adding on to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `super().__str__()` to get the default and then append what you want

```
>>> class Something(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return super().__str__() + "extra"
... 
>>> s = Something()
>>> 
>>> print(s)
<__main__.Something object at 0x7f976b5deeb8>extra
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted.